# replacing links after running javascript:void(0) on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, href, void

The following code is normally wrapped in an if statement to check if the browser is on a mobile device and if so then when you click on the main menu link it stops the href, hides the current nav bar links, then adds a new one.  This allows for the drop menu to stay dropped and you can click on the main menu link again so that the href works.  The problem is that you can only do this one time.  After the first click and the javascript:void(0) is run and the links are updated I cannot stop the href from going to its original location.  I need the javascript:void(0) to run on the first click of link each time and on the second click of the link redirect you to the respective page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.mobile-device > a').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.mobile-device > a').click(function(){
    $('.testing-a').css('display','block');
      $('.testing-this').css('display','none')
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault()` in such scenario.

Example ::

```
$('.mobile-device > a').click(function(evt){
   evt.preventDefault();
   $(this).attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
});
```

Comment: works, except i cant get it to return back to the default after the first click.  any idea of how to make that work?  thanks!!!!

Comment: found a solution!!  this adds and removes a class to the element and disables the original prevent default.  $('.mobile-device a').click(function (e){
   if($(this).hasClass('prevented')){
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).removeClass('prevented');
   }else{
       $(this).addClass('prevented');
   }
});